# On doing what a Brahmin and Kshatriya lose his caste?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins, kshatriya

1. By doing what things a Brahmin loses his caste?
2. On doing what a Kshatriya loses his caste?

Answer (score 10):

Generally by not following one's own duties (as per caste/Varna) and by following duties prescribed for others one looses their caste.

> Manu smriti 10.97. It is better (to discharge) one’s own (appointed)
> duty incompletely than to perform completely that of another; **for he
> who lives according to the law of another (caste) is instantly
> excluded from his own.**

A Brahmin falls from his caste by doing many acts like given below:

> 10.92. By (selling) flesh, salt, and lac a Brahmana at once becomes an outcast; by selling milk he becomes (equal to) a Sudra in three days.
>
> 10.93. But by willingly selling in this world other (forbidden) commodities, a Brahmana assumes after seven nights the character of a
> Vaisya.

In times of distress a Kshatriya can adopt the modes of living that are meant for castes lower than him (Vaishya and Shudra) but he can not adopt the mode meant for Brahmins.

> 10.95. A Kshatriya who has fallen into distress, may subsist by all these (means); but he must never arrogantly adopt the mode of life
> (prescribed for his) betters.

So if Kshatriyas take up teaching or they accept gifts then they become fallen because such acts are forbidden for them.

> 10.75. Teaching, studying, sacrificing for himself, sacrificing for others, making gifts and receiving them are the six acts (prescribed)
> for a Brahmana.
>
> 10.76. But among the six acts (ordained) for him three are his means of subsistence, (viz.) sacrificing for others, teaching, and accepting
> gifts from pure men.
>
> 10.77. (Passing) from the Brahmana to the Kshatriya, three acts (incumbent on the former) are forbidden, (viz.) teaching, sacrificing
> for others, and, thirdly, the acceptance of gifts.

Comment: Is teaching only meant for teaching Vedas or any type of teaching ? What is the sanskrit word used for teaching in this verse ? Because Arjuna being a Kshatriya was teacher for Satyaki.

Comment: Teaching Vedas is meant .. a Kshatriya is not allowed to teach scriptures and become a Diksha Guru . Only Brahmins have that right .. But Ksatriyas can be Siksha Gurus @river