# By performing what acts does a brahmin become outcaste?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, brahmins, chandala

I want to know about all the acts on doing which a brahmin becomes outcaste or chandala!

Comment: By not performing sandhyavandana thrice a day for 3 consecutive days, a brahmana becomes a shudra according to the Devibhagavatapurana.

Comment: See this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51609/4732